# Use Laravel validations when html input names vary from column name

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I cannot get passed `required` validation in my Laravel app.

This is the validation rule I have...

```
$rules = [
   'email' => 'required|unique:members|max:100',
];
```

The specific column name is `email`. The HTML page input field name is `emailAddress`

What to do in these situations ? How to tell this validation which request field to check ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem...

It's the input field names that validation checks. Not column names.

The problem here is the `unique` validation rule of the email field. I had to speficify which column to check for already stored emails.

Like this

```
unique:members,email
```

I had to use the column name after the table name separated by a `,` (comma).

So, the rule will be like

```
$rules = [
    'emailAddress' => 'required|unique:members,email|max:100',
];
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't check against column names in validation, just use the input name.

```
$rules = [
   'emailAddress' => 'required|unique:members|max:100',
];
```

I guess to be more clear: the Request instance is what is checked. Validation doesn't interact with the database, it interacts with the Request

Comment: I tried that and had `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'emailAddress' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Oh, then the problem isn't with validation at that point. When you go to put it in the database you need to convert the Request's version of the column to one that is acceptable by your table.

Comment: No, actually, the problem here is the `unique` validation rule of the `email` field. I had to speficify which column to check for already stored emails. Was able to fix the bug. Thanks, your answer was helpful!

Comment: Oh I see, glad to be of some help. Good luck with your application and be sure to accept your answer so anyone else looking will know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `name` attribute to `email`.

Or you can use validation rules like this:

```
'emailAddress' => 'required|unique:members|max:100',
```

And then in controller method do this:

```
Model::create([
    'email' => $request->emailAddress,
]);
```

Comment: No, in this case, I cannot touch the front-end. It's another party who implement the UIs

Comment: @TharinduLucky then do the second one.

Comment: Actually, the problem here wass the `unique` validation rule of the `email ` field. I had to speficify which column to check for already stored emails. Was able to fix the bug. Thanks, your answer was helpful!